# iframe in firefox

Tags: html, firefox, iframe

I am using this code to load http://x.net in a iframe, the code is w3 validated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
    <head> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
    <title>Store</title> 

    </head> 
<body style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; background-color: #9e0000;"> 
    <div style="width: 100%; background-color: #9e0000; overflow: hidden; width:800px; padding-left:55px;background-image:url(http://x.net/images/MaintenceMode_icon.png); background-repeat:no-repeat; margin:auto; background-position:0 50%;" id="maintain"> 
    <h1 style="color:#fff; margin-bottom: 0px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight:bold; font-size:30px;">Maintenance Mode</h1> 
    <p style="color:#fff; margin-top: 0px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight:bold; font-size:14px;">Your store is in Maintenance Mode and not viewable by the public. Go to your
        <a href="http://y.net" style="color:#fff; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight:bold; font-size:14px;">settings page</a> to change this.</p> 
    </div> 
    <iframe src="http://x.net/" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" name="Main" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px;"></iframe> 
</body> 
</html>
```

The problem is this code working fine, but in the firefox browser the iframe isn't loading. Any suggestion? And pls don't suggest to remove iframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The frame loads for me in Iceweasel 4 and Firefox 3, but there's no such page.

If it doesn't work for you, install firebug: http://getfirebug.com/, and it will help you diagnose the problem.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: @afh, thanks. you should have put that into a comment though, and not a separate answer.

Comment: ah, sorry, I meant firefox 3: Mozilla/5.0